# La figure de style qui consiste à personnaliser « il » a-t-elle un nom?

Tags: usage, pronoms, figure-de-style

Le pronom [*il*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il) est impersonnel quand il est employé avec des verbes exprimant un phénomène naturel :

> Il pleut;
>   Il fait beau;
>   Il vente.

Cependant, certains auteurs<sup>*1*</sup> rendent ce pronom personnel en utilisant à la fois un tel verbe, et un verbe clairement personnel. Par exemple :

> Il avait longtemps hésité avant de commencer à pleuvoir.

Dans le même genre, on peut aussi simplement personnaliser un objet lui-même :

> La pluie avait longtemps hésité avant de commencer à tomber.
>   Le soleil s'était levé à contrecœur.

Cette figure de style a-t-elle un nom ? Doit-on considérer de telles phrases comme incorrectes, et si oui, pourquoi exactement ? (Sur un plan purement grammatical, je ne vois rien à leur reprocher.) Peut-on simplement invoquer la liberté de création artistique pour la défendre ?

<sup>*1.* Terry Pratchett utilise beaucoup ce genre de style, mais j'avoue ne pas en connaître de francophones. La phrase citée est une invention de votre serviteur, qui n'hésiterait pas une seconde à l'utiliser si jamais il écrivait de la fiction.</sup>

Comment: Je suis sûr qu'un certains nombres d'auteurs francophones ont utilisé des tournures de style similaires. Le premier me venant à l'esprit est Desproges, qui aimait bien ce genre de badineries linguistiques (de tête: "à l'heure où Phoebus darde encore ses rayons dans sa poche"), sans parler de Boris Vian, bien sûr, qui en a presque fait sa spécialité (aussi de tête, encore moins certain): "La moutarde ne faisait pas long feu aux pieds d'Amadis" etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est plutôt le traducteur que tu devrais nommer, même si Pratchett utilise la même figure de style en anglais. Ici, je dirais qu'il s'agit simplement d'une [personnification](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personnification) : le monde qu'il décrit a un aspect animiste, des concepts comme le soleil et la pluie, ou encore la chance et le destin, sont des entités pensantes. La phrase suivante (qui procède de la même idée même si elle n'utilise pas la même structure grammaticale), par exemple, est très souvent citée (je ne sais pas comment le traducteur l'a rendue en français) :

> *Thunder rolled. It rolled a six.*

Comment: Je me demande si on arriverait à trouver un exemple qui ne soit pas de Pratchett.

Comment: @Gilles Il est traduit par « Le tonnerre roula... Il donna un six. »

Comment: @Evpok je suis bien content de les lire en VO alors.

Answer (score 3):

Grevisse encore...

> Un grand nombre de **verbes personnels** [...] peuvent être **construits impersonnellement** ; ils sont alors généralement suivis d'un nom, d'un pronom, d'un infinitif, d'une proposition conjonctive, séquence qu'on appelle traditionnellement sujet réel.

Il me semble qu'il s'agit de cette construction que beaucoup d'auteurs ont utilisé pour faire des effets (*Il pleure dans mon cœur / Comme il pleut sur la ville* de Verlaine p.e.)

---

Pour expliquer mon point de vue, commençons par la progression :

> Je mange.
>   Je commence à manger.
>   J'hésite à manger.
>   J'hésite avant de commencer à manger.

Il n'y a ici aucun problème.  Prenons un sujet inanimé.

> La pierre tombe.
>   La pierre commence à tomber.
>   La pierre hésite à tomber.
>   La pierre hésite avant de commencer à tomber.

Il y a une légère tension sur les deux dernières phrases (et encore plus sur la dernière).  Elle n'est pas grammaticale mais due au sens d'*hésiter* qui est le plus souvent employé avec un sujet conscient, et ce plus encore pour la forme intransitive. Cette tension « anime » en quelque sorte la pierre

Poursuivons avec les formes impersonnelles.

> Il pleut.
>   Il commence à pleuvoir.
>   Il hésite à pleuvoir.
>   Il hésite avant de commencer à pleuvoir.

À nouveau une tension sur les deux dernières phrases conduisant à une « animation » de la pluie. Sur la dernière phrase la tension n'est plus uniquement due au sens, elle est aussi grammaticale. Construire impersonnellement *hésiter* dans sa forme intransitive choquerait s'il n'était pas accompagné de « avant de commencer à pleuvoir. »  Ce qui sauve la construction, c'est peut-être qu'elle peut être comprise comme une ellipse remplaçant « Il hésite à pleuvoir avant de commencer à pleuvoir. »

Comment: C'est le contraire : ici un verbe impersonnel est construit personnellement.

Comment: Dans le cas de Pratchett, je suis d'accord.  Mais un _Il avait longtemps hésité avant de commencer à pleuvoir._ isolé passerait bien sans avoir un univers aussi animiste. _Il ne va pas tarder à pleuvoir._ me semble même courant.

Comment: Tes deux exemples ne sont pas la même construction grammaticale : *tarder à* n'implique forcément pas d'entité qui tarde ([« l'heure me tarde de partir »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tarder)), alors que *hésiter* si.

Comment: Oui, c'est un peu ce que je pensais aussi - [tarder](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tarder) est prévu pour ce genre d'emploi en standard.

Answer (score 0):

C'est tout simplement un cas particulier de zeugma, qui s'appuie sur une personnification partielle d'un sujet par essence impersonnel.